# On the transition functions in vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

I was studying vector bundles and didn't get the transition function's definition. Suppose we have two trivializations $\phi_U, \phi_V$. Taking the composition $\phi_u^{-1}\circ\phi_V: (U \cap V) \times \mathbb{R}^n \to (U \cap V) \times \mathbb{R}^n$ on the intersection, my textbook says that:

$$(x, v) \mapsto (x, g_{UV}(v))$$

Where $g_{UV}: (U \cap V) \to GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.

I understood why we have the identity on the first coordinate, but in my mind the second one should be the image $f(x, v)$ of a continuous function $f: (U \cap V) \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, only. From cartesian closedness of $Set$ we get a unique $g_{UV}: (U \cap V) \to \{g| g: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n\}$ from $f$, but I can't see how we can assure the linear structure on the codomain. Somebody could help me in that?

Comment: Note that if $p$ is the bundle projection then $\Phi_V: p^{-1}(v) \to \{v\}\times \mathbb{R}^n$ is per definition of trivialization a linear isomorphism.

Comment: The second coordinate arises simply from the fact that for each $v\in \mathbb R^n$ there is a $unique$ invertible linear transformation $g_{UV}(v):\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$, namely the Jacobian matrix of the map $\phi_u^{-1}\circ\phi_V$

Comment: The second coordinate should be $g_{UV}(x)v$ with $\forall x\in U\cap V, g_{UV}(x) \in GL_n(\Bbb R)$. In other words, $g_{UV}$ is a map from $U\cap V$ to $GL_n(\Bbb R)$